# Display list item elements in different columns

Tags: html, css, datalife-engine

I'm trying to change the looks of a DataLife Engine template, and I'm wondering if you could help me with alignment.

I have some info displayed in a colum, like this:

```
<div class="short-description">
    <div  class="table">
      <ul class="table">

        <li>A</li>

        <li class="odd">B</li>

        <li>C</li>

        <li class="odd">D</li>

        <li>E</li><br>

      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

This looks like

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

I want them to display like this:

```
A    B    C
D    E
```

The content of each "cell" can be different. E.g. if **B** has more contents, I'd like to adjust the columns as follows:

```
A    B    C
     B
     B
D    E
```

So it would stretch down until all info is displayed. The class odd just changes the color of that cell.

Here is the [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2tEQX/).

Comment: make jsfiddle next time

Comment: Oh, sorry i never worked with it. I'll try putting it in and i'll let you know when it's edited.

Comment: @oboshto i've added the link. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do that, you could display the list-items as `inline-block` elements, as follows:

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    font: 0/0 a;  /* Remove space characters between inline-block elements */
}

ul li {
    font: 16px/1 Arial, sans-erif;  /* Reset the font property */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;     /* <-- keep the inline elements at the top    */

    background-color: #ddd;  /* For the demo */
    margin: 5px;             /* For the demo */
    width: 200px;            /* For the demo */
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/9gBJe/)**.

Comment: Hi there @Hashem, here you have a link of JSFiddle of my code http://jsfiddle.net/2tEQX/

Can you help me edit this one? I've tried puting the with to 33,3% but it doesn't work :S

Comment: @PedroLino I'll try my best.

Comment: @PedroLino Some of HTML elements / CSS selectors are not used , Should I remove them from the fiddle?

Comment: Ok, i think i figured it out. The problem is it doesn't adjust to the dimention of the li cell. If i put BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB it just overlaps the other li... :/

Shure shure, edit it at your likes :)

Comment: @PedroLino You could use `word-break: break-all;` to break the line. Check **[this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/TYnFL/2/)**.

Comment: Ok its working :) I have another question. http://jsfiddle.net/2tEQX/2/

Has you can see here, start displaying from the bottom. Is there a way to put the displaing on the top like A?

Comment: vertical-align: top;
I've got it. :) Thank you

Comment: @PedroLino I was writing to you :) you could use `vertical-align: top;` **[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/2tEQX/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Look at [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/oboshto/3cF3z/)

```
.table ul{
    list-style: none;
    width: 180px;
    height: auto;
}

.table li{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 50px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) It was missing the vertical-align: top; :)