# CSS: List with images and text. Make Responsive

Tags: css, image, text, grid, responsive-design

So I've the following scenario:

Enter this jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/diqax/1/edit

If you notice this is a list, each list item has an image with text, the problem I'm facing is that I want the list items that are on the bottom to push down based on the height of the largest item with text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should change the display type of the list items to `inline-block` instead of using `float`, then use `vertical-align: top;` to align the inline block elements vertically.

```css
#gallery li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  /* other styles here... */
}
```

**[Online Demo](http://jsbin.com/tehurajo/1/edit)**.

For further info refer to [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21409424/display-list-item-elements-in-different-columns/21409646#21409646), also in order to remove the white space between inline(-block) elements, you can [refer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875226/space-between-nowrap-inline-blocks/21875532#21875532).

Comment: Make sure you remove any white space between your <li> tags or you will have a 'word space' between elements. i.e. </li><li>

Comment: @HashemQolami Lets say I wanted to add a text saying "Read More" at the bottom of the text, how do I make sure the text always stays at the bottom ?

Comment: @EricBergman Is this what you mean? http://jsbin.com/tehurajo/3/edit
If you append the *Read More* text/link into the paragraphs, you can force the link to be displayed at a new line by `a:before { content: '';   display: block; }`.

Comment: @Hashem Qolami I want all the "Read More" links to be aligned on the same line regardless of the content. What I tried is making the "Read More" link absolute and its parent relative and add bottom:0 to it but the problem with that is that if the text increases it will overlap the Read More text.

Comment: @EricBergman If these contents are summary, why don't you limit the words? or the lines? Take a look at: http://jsbin.com/tehurajo/6/edit If you were interested, follow this approach: http://www.css-101.org/articles/line-clamp/line-clamp_for_non_webkit-based_browsers.php or this one: http://codepen.io/romanrudenko/pen/ymHFh